# Strong and Weak Interactions

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction, strong-force

How do I determine whether an interactions is strong or weak if what i've been given is just the particles and the type of reaction:

Determine whether the following are strong or weak interactions?

- a muon decays
- a kaon decays
- pions are produced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different arguments to use depending on the reaction. For instance :

- muon decay is due to weak interaction, leptons are not concerned by strong
- kaon decay, is also due to weak interaction, because kaons have a strange number equal to $+1$ while its decay products have no strangeness at all
- if pions are produced, it is likely to be a strong interaction process (pions being the lightest mesons, they are massively produced in hadrons collisions for instance). But once again you can think of processes involving weak interactions with pions in the final state; for instance when kaon decays

Your best tool to discriminate between strong and weak processes is to look at quantum numbers which are conserved by the former but not by the latter (strangeness, charmness, etc). If information is given, you can also use the fact that strong processes usually happen much faster than weak ones